# linear mixed model for gene expression data in R

Tags: lme4

I have gene expression data for multiple genotypes as TPM matrix:

```
gene    Sample1 Sample2 Sample3
gene A  12.6    3.5     6.7
gene B  7.8     9.7     4.3
```

In the matrix, genes are in rows, columns have samples with TPM values for each gene across the samples. I want to run a linear mixed effect model using `lme4`.

I will appreciate any help on to run a linear mixed model on my data. Thank you!

Comment: Did you look into this https://m-clark.github.io/docs/mixedModels/anovamixed.html

Comment: Thank you! To apply linear mixed model in my case, I do not have any column labeled as TPM. I think I need to modify the model with an array to pick TPM values in rows for each gene. That's what I am not an expert case.

Comment: What are these values `12.6` etc? these are normalized read counts? When you apply model it will apply to all rows (genes) and you don't need to run the loop for each row (gene)

Comment: Yes, these are normalized read counts (TPM values got by using salmon). I want to run model for each gene separately to get values for each gene. I want to use use TPM values i.e., 12.6 etc as response variable.

Comment: You may get more help from https://www.biostars.org

Comment: also a good resource   <- https://compgenomr.github.io/book/